# Assistance in setting up new APC Smart-UPS RT on a new VMware enviroment

Tags: windows-server-2003, snmp, ups

I'm new to the realm of setting up a APC Smart-UPS RT 8000VA UPS with a management network card (AP9618). The project calls for the upgrade of the firmware for the network card to the newest and greatest. It also calls for the Powerchute Business Software to be installed with notifications setup per email for temperature, shutdown, and battery low.  I know I'll have to use the serial cable to flash the firmware and install the software on one server 2003 box. Also on that server I'll have to install the software and setup the GUI (IP address) interface.

Whats confusing the most is the whole process, and steps to use without taking down the network, which would be very bad. In flashing the firmware does it take down the UPS? Do i have to run BOOTP commands to setup the network card? Also no agents will be used on any of the VWware OS's and no SNMP trap will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the firmware on the card can be done over the Ethernet and doesn't cause the UPS to power off.

That particular APC card will pull an IP address using DHCP or BOOTP, or can be configured using RARP (see http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z5QDZ_R0_EN.pdf).